# JQUERY disable next all inputs, if focussed input is empty

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to disable next all inputs, if current input is empty.
suppose if a user comes back after filling all the details and lets say deletes **state** input then it should disable next all inputs.

My HTML snippet:

```
<form action="#" class="shippingForm" id="ShippingForm" method="post" name="shippingForm">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="form__block full-width form-select">
          <label class="form__label">Country <sup>*</sup></label>
          <input id="shippingAddressCountry" name="shippingAddressCountry" type="hidden">
          <div class="typeahead__container">
            <div class="typeahead__field">
              <span class="typeahead__query"><input autocomplete="off" class="js-typeahead-country_v1 form__input full-width step" name="country_v1[query]" placeholder="Country" type="search"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="form__block full-width form-select">
          <label class="form__label">State <sup>*</sup></label>
          <input id="shippingAddressState" name="shippingAddressState" type="hidden">
          <div class="typeahead__container">
            <div class="typeahead__field">
              <span class="typeahead__query"><input autocomplete="off" class="js-typeahead-state_v1 form__input full-width step" disabled name="state_v1[query]" placeholder="State" type="search"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="form__block full-width form-select">
          <label class="form__label">City<sup>*</sup></label>
          <input class="form__input full-width" id="shippingCity" name="shippingCity" type="hidden">
          <div class="typeahead__container">
            <div class="typeahead__field">
              <span class="typeahead__query"><input autocomplete="off" class="js-typeahead-city_v1 form__input full-width step" disabled name="city_v1[query]" placeholder="Search" type="search"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="form__block full-width form-select">
          <label class="form__label">Address<sup>*</sup></label>
          <input class="form__input full-width" id="shippingAddress1" name="shippingAddress1" type="hidden">
          <div class="typeahead__container">
            <div class="typeahead__field">
              <span class="typeahead__query"><input autocomplete="off" class="js-typeahead-address_v1 form__input full-width step" disabled name="address_v1[query]" placeholder="Search" type="search"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="form__block full-width form-select">
          <label class="form__label">Zip<sup>*</sup></label>
          <input class="form__input full-width" id="shippingPostalCode" name="shippingPostalCode" type="hidden">
          <div class="typeahead__container">
            <div class="typeahead__field">
              <span class="typeahead__query"><input autocomplete="off" class="js-typeahead-zip_v1 form__input full-width step" disabled name="zip_v1[query]" placeholder="Search" type="search"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Jquery

```
(function() {
  $('.step').keyup(function() {
    var mystep = $('.step');
    var nextstep = mystep.eq(mystep.index(this) + 1);
    var next_step = $(this).next('.step');
    var all_next_steps = $(this).nextAll('.step');
    // If the element *has* a value
    if ($(this).val()) {
      nextstep.attr('disabled', false);
    }
    // If the element doesn't have a value
    else {
      // Clear the value of all next steps and disable
      all_next_steps.val('');
      all_next_steps.attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });

  $(input).change(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == '') {
      $(this).nextAll('.step').val('');
      $(this).nextAll('.step').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  })
})()
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/etg35nt1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checking for the step next to the current input step element

but in your markup it does not exist the way you are looking for ,it is present within a div and in which the step element is present

so you need to change your code to the following snippet

check this

```js
(function() {
  $('.step').keyup(function() {
    var mystep = $('.step');
    var nextstep = mystep.eq(mystep.index(this) + 1);
    var next_step = $(this).parents('.col-sm-6').next().find('.step');
    var all_next_steps = $(this).parents('.col-sm-6').nextAll().find('.step');
    // alert(all_next_steps.length);
    // If the element *has* a   value
    if ($(this).val()) {
      nextstep.attr('disabled', false);
    }
    // If the element doesn't have a value
    else {
      // Clear the value of all next steps and disable
      all_next_steps.val('');
      all_next_steps.attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });

  $('input').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {

      //$($0).parents('.col-sm-6').nextAll().find('.step').attr('disabled',true)
      $(this).parents('.col-sm-6').nextAll().find('.step').attr('disabled', true).val('');

    }
  })
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" class="shippingForm" id="ShippingForm" method="post" name="shippingForm">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="form__block full-width form-select">
      <label class="form__label">Country <sup>*</sup>
      </label>
      <input id="shippingAddressCountry" name="shippingAddressCountry" type="hidden">
      <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
          <span class="typeahead__query"><input autocomplete="off" class="js-typeahead-country_v1 form__input full-width step" name="country_v1[query]" placeholder="Country" type="search"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="form__block full-width form-select">
      <label class="form__label">State <sup>*</sup>
      </label>
      <input id="shippingAddressState" name="shippingAddressState" type="hidden">
      <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
          <span class="typeahead__query"><input autocomplete="off" class="js-typeahead-state_v1 form__input full-width step" disabled name="state_v1[query]" placeholder="State" type="search"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="form__block full-width form-select">
      <label class="form__label">City<sup>*</sup>
      </label>
      <input class="form__input full-width" id="shippingCity" name="shippingCity" type="hidden">
      <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
          <span class="typeahead__query"><input autocomplete="off" class="js-typeahead-city_v1 form__input full-width step" disabled name="city_v1[query]" placeholder="Search" type="search"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="form__block full-width form-select">
      <label class="form__label">Address<sup>*</sup>
      </label>
      <input class="form__input full-width" id="shippingAddress1" name="shippingAddress1" type="hidden">
      <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
          <span class="typeahead__query"><input autocomplete="off" class="js-typeahead-address_v1 form__input full-width step" disabled name="address_v1[query]" placeholder="Search" type="search"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="form__block full-width form-select">
      <label class="form__label">Zip<sup>*</sup>
      </label>
      <input class="form__input full-width" id="shippingPostalCode" name="shippingPostalCode" type="hidden">
      <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
          <span class="typeahead__query"><input autocomplete="off" class="js-typeahead-zip_v1 form__input full-width step" disabled name="zip_v1[query]" placeholder="Search" type="search"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Please check this following link might be you want achive something like this http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/2882

```
(function() {

var a = $('.step');
a.attr('disabled',true);
a.eq(0).attr('disabled',false);

 $('.step').keyup(function() {
    var mystep = $('.step');
var nextstep = mystep.eq(mystep.index(this) + 1);
var next_step = $(this).next('.step');
var all_next_steps = $(this).nextAll('.step');

if ($(this).val()) {
  nextstep.attr('disabled', false);
}
// If the element doesn't have a value
else {
  // Clear the value of all next steps and disable
  all_next_steps.val('');
  all_next_steps.attr('disabled', true);
}
});
```

})()